# Number of ways of choosing $a,b,c$ and $d$ such that $a+b+c+d=1$ and $a^2+b^2+c^2+d^2=\max\{a,b,c,d\}$

Tags: combinatorics, contest-math

> Let $a,b,c$ and $d$ be non-negative real numbers where $a+b+c+d=1$. The number of different ways in which we can choose these numbers such that $a^2+b^2+c^2+d^2=\max\{a,b,c,d\}$ is?
>
> Source: ISI B math 7/18/2021

WLOG let $\max\{a,b,c,d\}=a$ then $a^2+b^2+c^2+d^2=a$ or we can write  $b^2+c^2+d^2=a-a^2 \le \frac{1}{4}$. I am unable to find a way ahead.

Comment: Hint: Assuming that $a$ is the maximum, let $b=xa$, $c=ya$, $d=za$ and then consider $a+xa+ya+za=1$ together with $a^2+(xa)^2+(ya)^2+(za)^2=a$.

Answer (score 1):

If the numbers $a, b, c, d$ solve these equations, then we can order the numbers in such a way that they are in decreasing order. Let $x_1, x_2, x_3, x_4$ be a solution for which $$x_1 \geq x_2 \geq x_3 \geq x_4.$$ It follows that $$x_1 + x_2 + x_3 + x_4 = 1,$$ and that $$x_1^2 + x_2^2 + x_3^2 + x_4^2 = x_1.$$ We can rewrite the second equation as $$x_1 (1 - x_1) - x_2^2 - x_3^2 - x_4^2 = 0.$$ Substituting $$1 - x_1 = x_2 + x_3 + x_4$$ into the previous equation and factoring gives $$x_2 (x_1 - x_2) + x_3 (x_1 - x_3) + x_4 (x_1 - x_4) = 0.$$ The above is a sum of nonnegative numbers which evaluates to $0$. The only way that this is possible is if *all* the summands are $0$ as well.

Thus $$x_2 (x_1 - x_2) = x_3 (x_1 - x_3) = x_4 (x_1 - x_4) = 0.$$ This tells us that for each $x_i$ where $2 \leq i \leq 4$, exactly one of the following statements is true:

- $x_i = 0$, or
- $x_i = x_1$ which is nonzero.

There are very few numbers $x_1, x_2, x_3, x_4$ which satisfy all these conditions, and they are

- $1, 0, 0, 0$;
- $1/2, 1/2, 0, 0$;
- $1/3, 1/3, 1/3, 0$; and
- $1/4, 1/4, 1/4, 1/4$.

These choices are forced by the amount of zeros, the numbers being decreasing, each nonzero number being equal, and the sum being $1$. It’s easy to check that these numbers satisfy the other equation as well.

The total number of possibilities for the numbers $a, b, c, d$ is then decided by how many zeros there are and where they are placed. This is given by

$$\begin{align}
\binom{4}{3} + \binom{4}{2} + \binom{4}{1} + \binom{4}{0} &= 2^4 - 1 \\ 
&= \fbox{15}.
\end{align}
$$